# Empty AncestorListener results in method call

Tags: java, swing, debugging, profiling

i'm a bit confused about the behavior of my java application :)

- A JPanel has an AncestorListener in which a method x() is called if the ancestor is added
- The JPanel is added to a JScrollPane as the **first** tab
- The JScrollPane has **another** AncestorListener

If the scroll panel gets visible, the method x() is executed twice

- The first call of x() is triggered by adding the panel
- The second call of x() is triggerd by showing the panel

The confusing part is, that the second call is caused by the AncestorListener of the ScrollPane, even if the listener has an **empty** implementation.
There is no second call, if i remove the listener.

Can anyone explain how a listener with an empty implementation can result in a method call, or how i can debug/profile this problem?

Thank you in advance

Best regards

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its not possible to run the application without a specific hardware. The application is also very complex, so it is possibly a side effect. Thats the reason for the abstract description of the problem. I'm looking for a hint or a possiblity to find/debug the problem, rather than a explicit solution

Comment: Didn’t ask for the application, I asked for something which can replicate the issue you’re having